# EF Core: Update-Database command not creating user tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) I created an `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1 - Code first` app on `VS2017 ver 15.3.3`. The only difference between the tutorial and my app is that I chose `Individual User Accounts` option and I'm using `SQL Server 2012 EXPRESS` Db instead of LocalDb. Following commands run fine and do create Blogging database with Blogs and Posts tables. Note: I've not upgraded to .NET Core 2.0 yet on both the computers for compatibility issues with some of our existing applications.

```
PM> Add-Migration myFirstMigration -context BloggingContext
PM> Update-Database -context BloggingContext
```

**ISSUE**

But when I run the following command to generate user tables (ASPNETUsers, ASPNETRols etc) the command runs without any error but the user tables are not created. This was not happening before I upgraded VS2017 to ver 15.3.3. Also, on my other computer (Windows 10 with SQLEXPRESS 2014) I don't have such a problem. This computer is Windows 7. What could possibly be the issue here - and what I may be missing here?

```
Update-Database -context BloggingContext
```

**.csproj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-ForgotPassword-B181AA40-BA34-4A36-A650-38857D8E8177</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**ApplicationDbContextModelShapshot.cs**

```
[DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
{
    protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "1.0.0-rc3")
            .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("Id");

                b.Property<string>("ConcurrencyStamp")
                    .IsConcurrencyToken();

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);

                b.Property<string>("NormalizedName")
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("NormalizedName")
                    .HasName("RoleNameIndex");

                b.ToTable("AspNetRoles");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRoleClaim<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<string>("ClaimType");

                b.Property<string>("ClaimValue");

                b.Property<string>("RoleId")
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("RoleId");

                b.ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserClaim<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<string>("ClaimType");

                b.Property<string>("ClaimValue");

                b.Property<string>("UserId")
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("UserId");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("LoginProvider");

                b.Property<string>("ProviderKey");

                b.Property<string>("ProviderDisplayName");

                b.Property<string>("UserId")
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasKey("LoginProvider", "ProviderKey");

                b.HasIndex("UserId");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserRole<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("UserId");

                b.Property<string>("RoleId");

                b.HasKey("UserId", "RoleId");

                b.HasIndex("RoleId");

                b.HasIndex("UserId");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserToken<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("UserId");

                b.Property<string>("LoginProvider");

                b.Property<string>("Name");

                b.Property<string>("Value");

                b.HasKey("UserId", "LoginProvider", "Name");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUserTokens");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("ForgotPassword.Models.ApplicationUser", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("Id");

                b.Property<int>("AccessFailedCount");

                b.Property<string>("ConcurrencyStamp")
                    .IsConcurrencyToken();

                b.Property<string>("Email")
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);

                b.Property<bool>("EmailConfirmed");

                b.Property<bool>("LockoutEnabled");

                b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("LockoutEnd");

                b.Property<string>("NormalizedEmail")
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);

                b.Property<string>("NormalizedUserName")
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);

                b.Property<string>("PasswordHash");

                b.Property<string>("PhoneNumber");

                b.Property<bool>("PhoneNumberConfirmed");

                b.Property<string>("SecurityStamp");

                b.Property<bool>("TwoFactorEnabled");

                b.Property<string>("UserName")
                    .HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("NormalizedEmail")
                    .HasName("EmailIndex");

                b.HasIndex("NormalizedUserName")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasName("UserNameIndex");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUsers");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRoleClaim<string>", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole")
                    .WithMany("Claims")
                    .HasForeignKey("RoleId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserClaim<string>", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("ForgotPassword.Models.ApplicationUser")
                    .WithMany("Claims")
                    .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin<string>", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("ForgotPassword.Models.ApplicationUser")
                    .WithMany("Logins")
                    .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserRole<string>", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole")
                    .WithMany("Users")
                    .HasForeignKey("RoleId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                b.HasOne("ForgotPassword.Models.ApplicationUser")
                    .WithMany("Roles")
                    .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the above test by selecting ASP.NET Core 2.0 template on another computer that has `.NET Core 2.0` and `VS2017 ver 15.3.3` and everything worked fine as expected - with same SQL Server version `SQLEXPRESS2012`. Blogging Db was created with Blogs and Posts tables and user tables ASPNETUsers, ASPNETRoles etc. So problem seems to be when you have .NET Core 1.1.1 on your system with `VS2017 ver 15.3.3` and your are trying to create an ASP.NET Core 1.1.1 web app with `Individual User Accounts` then `ApplicationDbContext` does not work.

Comment: Since the command is running without error, can you try running the command outside of Visual Studio from your project root? `dotnet ef migrations add myFirstMigration  --verbose` if that works without error, you should be able to run `dotnet ef database update --verbose --context BloggingContext`

Comment: @Peter The issue is on ApplicationDbContext. `PM> update-database works fine` on `BloggingContext`. From outside Visual Studio when I ran `dotnet ef migrations add myFirstMigration --verbose` it, as expected, complained that there are two DbContext specify the one you need. So I specified `--context ApplicationDbContext` attribute value and it ran fine. Then I ran `dotnet ef database update --verbose --context ApplicationDbContext` that also ran with success. But still no user tables in Bloggings database.

Comment: I forgot to mention the last command. Running `dotnet ef database update` will trigger actual table updates.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was eventually simple to resolve for me using Visual Studio 2017, using Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.5.. I wasn't receiving any error messages I just had to change this in my `appsettings.json`. I had to change "`Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;`" to this: "`Server=Localhost;`."  Then I ran the command, "`Update-Database`" and it created the tables.

Comment: This was the only one that worked from all over the internet! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When running commands to add migrations and update database you are referencing BloggingContext and you are showing us a snapshot of ApplicationDbContext. ApplicationDbContext comes with Individual User Accounts template that you have chosen, so if you want Identity tables (User table is one of them) you should extend ApplicationDbContext instead of creating a new one.